# ImageView with AnchorPane resizing

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2

I use Scene Builder 1.1.
I added `ImageView` with `Image` on `AnchorPane`, and i want it resizes together, but point "resize"
in the `ImageViews`properties is inactive.. as the result all controls which are on the ImageView dont resize too.. Didt find answer, despite questions are ease..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try binding the ImageView fitWidth/Height property to the anchor pane width and height:

```
AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
ImageView view = new ImageView();

view.fitWidthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
view.fitHeightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
```

- chooks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own  listener for when the parent pane is resized, and then implement the resizing of the imageview on that listener.